# Not triggering the click event - while i use inline template in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I need to make just a small list of students, for that i made the inline template to make element and appending the click event...

But i unable to get the element event trigger and it's model...

how can i achieve this both?

my code:

```
define("appView", ["backbone"], function(Backbone){

    "use strict"

    var appView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template:_.template("<li><%= name %></li>"),
        events:{
            "click" : "listTrigger"
        },
        initialize:function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render:function(){
            return this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        },
        listTrigger:function(){
            console.log("List triggered", this.model); //not working...
        }
    });

    return{
        getView: appView
    }

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various of problems here:

1. A view's events around bound to the view's `el` but you neither populate `el` with HTML nor do you put the view's `el` into the DOM. Apparently you're doing `html = v.render()` and then adding `html` to the DOM.
2. Your template won't work with the usual Backbone approach. You'd end up with `<div><li>...</li></div>` as your HTML and that's not valid HTML; given invalid HTML, the browser will probably try to correct it and make a big mess.

If you want your view to be a single `<li>` then you'd want to use [`tagName`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) to tell Backbone to use an `<li>` and then put just the content into `template`:

```
tagName: 'li',
template: _.template('<%= name %>')
```

Then you'd have to fix your `render` to populate `this.el`:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
```

The `return this` is conventional so I added that to, doing that allows you to do things like this:

```
$('ul').append(v.render().el)
```

That pattern is not only convenient but will also be immediately recognized by anyone that has worked with Backbone.

Also, I'm assuming that whatever is using this view will be putting the instances into a `<ul>`, `<ol>`, or `<menu>` element as those are [the only valid parents for an `<li>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-context):

> **Permitted parent elements**
>
> `ul`, `ol`, `menu`